# Импорт ветки реестра через python

Tags: python, реестр

Всем привет.
Имеется экспортированная ветка реестра (.reg файл), в ней около 20 ключей. Подскажите как в питоне можно импортировать его обратно в реестр?

Comment: Это вопрос, какие у Python команды работы с директориями, и как создать файл и записать информацию в нём в одной из них, или это что-то более специфичное?

Comment: Скорее более специфичное, т.к. имеется ввиду импорт по другому пути реестра. (сейчас дополню основной вопрос)

Comment: https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/library/winreg.html